# TextEditingController.clear() does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to clear a form key controller on a network error. however `TextEditingController.clear()` is not working.

```dart
  late TextEditingController keyController;
  late TextEditingController passController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    keyController = TextEditingController();
    passController = TextEditingController();
  }

//...

if (resp.statusCode >= 400) {
   keyController.clear();
   passController.clear();
   formKey.currentState!.validate();
   return;
}
```

I have checked other threads with this question and tried all the solutions.

I have wrapped the `clear` calls in a `setState`. I have tried the change the focus using `FocusScope.of(context)` and also use `FocusNodes`. These are `TextFormField`, I have also tried `GlobalKey<FormState>.currentState.reset()` as well. Doesn't work.

I can't seem to work it our.

Thank you for your help

What might be causing this?

Comment: have you assigned controller to textfield ??

Comment: can you put the code that you implement of your text input field, and do you check the `resp.statuscode` result?, and where do you put your `if` function

Comment: Can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: did you try putting a `Key`on your `TextField` widget?

Comment: @ManishDayma Of course I wasn't assigning the controllers. Sometimes it is the most basic thing you fail at.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small sample application to demonstrate how to clear a field in a form - https://dartpad.dev/?id=009807fd2f3e96ebde61182b9fe506e4

Open the console, enter the data into the field. Wait a few seconds until the console shows "XMLHttpRequest error." and the field is cleared